# how to add contact in mobile contact list using content provider kolin android?

Tags: android, kotlin

> how to add contact in mobile contact list using content provider 
>   **please help me**

**here is an error**

```
val res = contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops)
```

Comment: here is a full code

Comment: ops.add(
            ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(
                    ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                    rawContactInsertIndex )
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, "9X-XXXXXXXXX")
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(Phone.TYPE, "1").build()
        )

Comment: ops.add(
            ContentProviderOperation
                .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValueBackReference(
                    ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,
                    rawContactInsertIndex
                )
                .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "Mike Sullivan")
                .build()
        )

Comment: try {
            val res = contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops)
           Toast.makeText(this, "contact add$res", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } catch (e: RemoteException) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: OperationApplicationException) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

Comment: Improved legibility (not enough to get a clear question).